# How Can I keep Selling Out Of Stock Products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

My client has just upgraded to a new POS system that manages stock and overwrites product data on woo/wp, and the client has had trouble with the "manage stock" setting being automatically applied on woo every time she updates a product on the POS system.

the idea of this is the product needs to show as available regardless of what the stock status. ALL products should show 'add to cart and be purchasable REGARDLESS of the stock status. Any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: Disable stock management ?  Click WooCommerce Click Settings Click Products Click Inventory Uncheck Enable stock management Click Save changes

Comment: I understand that setting, I've already tried that... I think it is the client's POS system that is selecting that setting..image ( https://prnt.sc/4_m4Zwg8615Z )

Comment: Allow backorders?

Comment: @Stender already did that..not working (https://prnt.sc/Hf_AH-K0Cdom)

Comment: Ask the POS devs how interacts with the woo. With provided info cant help much. Prob is API sync

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, this seems like an issue with the POS. I have tested enabling backorders on WooCommerce and was able to backorder products. Please see if you are able to share the code overwriting product data. As this probably shuts off the back order setting again.

My test case>

Product Configuration
[image]

Available Backorder
[image]

Page when setting is disabled. (what is probably happening to you)
[image]

If you are able to share part of the code I will be able to assist you with this issue because by the looks of it this is an issue with custom code and not with WooCommerce itself.

Keep in mind that this does look different from your webshop, as my test server is currently running a default WP theme.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details...but I've talked to the POS system team and they said they don't manage woo settings...and I'm not using any custom code here. This website is built on Oxygen builder...this is how it looks on the backend (https://prnt.sc/8h13PgbX_P1h) and in the front (https://prnt.sc/XFNsgrzPZ9yH)...I've tried every setting, but still no luck.

Comment: Do you have an overview of all plugins on the site? Maybe there is a plugin that conflicts with WooCommerce

Comment: yes, the client is using around 75+ plugins, lol...is there any way we can fix it by code??

Comment: I think theres a piece of code inside one of those plugins that is conflicting with backorders.

Comment: Ok...thank you so much for your help..I will check that..